# How to get data onto textbox in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Here I want to edit the available data from the database , so i am bit confused about how to get those data onto text boxes

```
    public string EditRegistrationForm(int ID)
    {
        string Msg = null;
        Database database = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
     //   List<Registrationform> results = new List<Registrationform>();
        try
        {
            string str = "Edit_RegistrationForm";
            DbCommand storedProcCommand = database.GetStoredProcCommand(str);
            database.AddInParameter(storedProcCommand, "@p_ID", DbType.Int64, ID);
            ds = database.ExecuteDataSet(storedProcCommand);

           Msg = "EditOperationSuccessful";
        //  ds = database.ExecuteDataSet(storedProcCommand);
            //results = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
            //          .Select(row => new Registrationform
            //          {
            //              Id = (int)(row["ID"]),
            //              Name = (row["Name"].ToString()),
            //              Age =(int) (row["Age"]),
            //              EMailId = (row["EMailId"].ToString()),
            //              phNumber = (row["phNumber"].ToString())
            //          }).ToList();
        }


        catch
        {
            Msg = "EditOperationFailed";
        }
        return Msg;
```

Comment: Are we talking about MVC pattern in general or are we talking about ASP.NET MVC... or what?

Comment: yes it is asp.net mvc

Comment: Then u have tp create an action inside a controller. Create a viewmodel with required properties and fill them with your stuff you want to have in your view. Please take a look to the official documentation of [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc). There is everything explained.

Answer (score 0):

One of the simple way to pass data from controller to view is **ViewBag**

eg:

```
ViewBag.message = "Value to be shown in textbox";
```

Now create a view and access the viewbag there

eg:

```
@Html.TextBox("txtTitle", (string)ViewBag.message )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind data from your database to the view through the use of model

define your model as a class, you can add annotations that reflect on your view like validations

for example

```
public class Registration {
 public string Msg {get;set;}
}
```

then in the controller action call your function that retrieves the data from the database into the model

```
Registration reg=new Registration();
reg.Msg= callFunction();
```

then return the model in the View so that the view is bound to your model
    return View(reg);

and in the view you can leverage the Html Helpers

```
@Html.EditorFor(m=> m.Msg)
```